# How to pass variable from popup to content script?

Tags: javascript, html

How can i pass a variable from popup.html input to the content script fille?
For exemple popup.html

```
<body>
    <H1>MADE BY SK</H1>

    <input type="text" name="" id="nomeitem">Nome Item
    <input type="button" value="Guarda Valores" id="salvar" onclick="salvar()">
</body>
```

addtobasket.js

```
function salvar() {
    item_name = input("nomeitem").value
}
```

This is just an example i know code is totaly incorrect

Comment: You have to get the Element some how, like `const salvar = document.getElementById('salvar'); salvar.onclick = function(){ console.log(this.value) };`. Oh, that should be external JavaScript and get rid of your HTML `onclick` attribute, in that case.

Comment: I have 2 scripts the mais script is addtobasket and the backgroun and i want to get a value from the popup.html and pass it to an addtobasket.js variable

Comment: Are the scripts in the same HTML file. You have access to both if you use a `load` Event.

Comment: can you send me your discord?

Comment: You haven't asked a question that makes sense. I don't see a popup here at all. What do you mean by a popup? Most popups are not new windows, they are just HTML and CSS on the same page. If the popup is on a separate window  you can assign like `const openedWindow = open('yourWindow.html', 'your window');` then access the DOM, like: `openedWindow.document.getElementById('idHere');`.

Comment: True but its dificult to explain but here it goes. 
I'm creating an chrome extension that automatically buys clothes from a website
Popup.html is the interface and addtobasket.js is the script that interacts with the shop website
I want to take an input value and transfer it to the addtobasket script.
SK#4197 my discord if you want to add me

Comment: Have you tried `opener` in `addbasket.js`? That would give you the window  that opened it.

Comment: i dont know how to use it please add me to discord i will send you prints

Comment: Just use `opener` on `addbasket.js`. That would be the window that opened the HTML page. `opener.document.getElementById('yourId')`. Since `opener` is a property of `window` you can leave the `window` off of `window.opener`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [chrome messaging service](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) it will allow you to pass the value after content script is injected or you could use [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)

**using chrome messaging service**

In your **popup.js**

```
salvar.addEventListener('click',()=>{
       
        chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},(tabs)=>{
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,{message: "hello"},(resp)=>{ //specify the message 
                var div=document.createElement('div')
                div.innerHTML=`<p class="text-warning">Notification ${resp.msg}</p>`
                document.body.appendChild(div)
            })
        })
   })

 },false)
```

In your **content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request,sender,sendMessage)=>{
    value=request.message
//execute your code here 
 sendMessage({msg:'sent'})
```

**Using chrome.storage.local**

In your **popup.js**

```
chrome.storage.local.set({
    variable: data
},
 function () {
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: "content.js"
    });
});
```

In your **content.js**

```
chrome.storage.local.get("variable", function (data) {
          var getdata=data.variable
          // use getdata in your content script
  chrome.storage.local.remove("variable");// this is optional
});
```

Comment: its a litle hard to me to understand all that code can you add me to discord?SK#4197

Answer (score 0):

```js
function salvar() {
    var item_name = document.getElementById("nomeitem").value;
    console.log(item_name);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <H1>MADE BY SK</H1>

    <input type="text" name="" id="nomeitem" >Nome Item
    <input type="button" value="Guarda Valores" id="salvar" onclick="salvar()">
</body>
```

Comment: the script is outside of the popup like i have popup.html and i have addtobasket.js and i want go get the value from the input and get it on a addtobasket.js variable for example item_name

Comment: where are you calling your js file?

Comment: in the popup.html